# Pretend that file exists on a server safari

Tags: javascript, file, safari

So I have a webpage that seems to not work because a sound file is missing on the server.

If I check the console I get `[Error] failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (webpage.com/media/sound.m4a, line 0)`

> PS: i'm on safari 14.1.2 (14611.3.10.1.7) and macOS mojave.

If I inspect the page source I see that the entire `media` directory is non-existent, so I would need to pretend that the `media` directory exists too.

Maybe a command in the js console?

Now to clear this up I do not want to add a file to the server. I just want to trick safari into thinking that this file *is* on this server, and when the file is requested, to use a file that I choose.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this in the browser itself. But you could point it to a proxy that matches that URL and sends files.

Comment: look into [local overrides](https://webkit.org/web-inspector/local-overrides/)